# php pdo where clause

Tags: php, pdo

I have the following code for selecting from multiple tables where the order number matches.

```
$orderNumber = $_GET['orderNumber'];

$sql = $db->prepare("
                    SELECT
                        *
                    from `KC_Orders`
                        INNER JOIN
                            `KC_Payments`
                            on KC_Orders.orderNumber = KC_Payments.orderNumber
                        INNER JOIN
                            `KC_OrderStatus`
                            on KC_Orders.orderNumber = KC_OrderStatus.orderNumber
                        INNER JOIN
                            `KC_Statuses`
                            on KC_OrderStatus.statusID = KC_Statuses.statusID
                    WHERE
                        orderNumber= :orderNumber");

$sql->execute(array(':orderNumber' => $orderNumber));
$orderInfo = $sql->fetchAll();
```

Now when I `var_dump($orderInfo);` it returns: `array(0) { }` What is wrong? All the tables include the same `$orderNumber` field within it. If I take the WHERE part out it works just fine except it returns every row not just one. (obviosly).

Please help us!

Comment: your query is failing and you haven't bothered checking for failure, or turning on pdo's exception mode.

Comment: @MarcB Then show me how.

Comment: If you `echo $orderNumber;` before running `$sql->execute();` then do you get the expected result?

Comment: Yup get the order number.

Comment: So if you take your query and run it on MySQL WorkBench or PHPMyAdmin and manually replace `:orderNumber` with the order number then what do you get?

Comment: With my code, when I run it in PHPMyAdmin I get this error: `#1052 - Column 'orderNumber' in where clause is ambiguous`. If I replace `orderNumber = ` with `KC_Orders.orderNumber = ` I get this error: `#1054 - Unknown column 'CKO_52f1a5e3be38f' in 'where clause'`

Comment: Ok, now keep the `WHERE KC_Orders.orderNumber` as is and try `SELECT KC_Orders.orderNumber`. I think the `*` might also be causing some ambiguity issues

Comment: Okay, that worked. But I need to return every column not just the order number.

Comment: Every column from every table? Try specifying `KC_Orders.*, KC_Payments.*` and so forth. If that doesn't work then I believe you have to manually pick and choose the columns and you are SOL

Comment: haha! Okay Well I will try that. please place in an answer so I can accept.

Comment: Well let me know what works so that I don't post a half-baked answer please. Also I see you are new so I don't know when you are commenting here unless I remember to check this question in my history. You can type `@MonkeyZeus` and StackOverflow will alert me of your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify what the `OrderNumber` is from, and the `*` is from (what table). So try this new code:

```
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT KC_Orders.* from `KC_Orders` INNER JOIN `KC_Payments` on KC_Payments.orderNumber = KC_Orders.orderNumber INNER JOIN `KC_OrderStatus` on KC_OrderStatus.orderNumber = KC_Order.orderNumber INNER JOIN `KC_Statuses` on KC_Statuses.statusID = KC_OrderStatus.statusID WHERE KC_Orders.orderNumber= :orderNumber");
```

Comment: Still returns `array(0) { }`

Answer (score 0):

Ordernumber in where clause should have table prefix if it exists in multiple tables

Answer (score 0):

Try this

$orderNumber = (int)$_GET['orderNumber'];

Then where :ordernumber is put $orderNumber

Then execute

Comment: Try the stuff above or check out bindparam method of pdostatement then call execute